# How to use the WSL and CMD terminal from VsCode terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd

I can only use the `bash`, `tmux`, and `javascript debug terminal` in VsCode. I can't use the `CMD` and `WSL terminal`.

I tried to change it in the **default terminal profile** but there's no `CMD` and `WSL` there.

[image: No CMD and WSL in default terminal profile]

[image: No CMD and WSL Terminal in the options]

Answer (score 0):

Press on Configure Terminal Settings and open `setting.json` file and add this line

> `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",`

[Go to VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles) to learn more about terminal integration.

Comment: tried it, didn't work